# grails createCriteria how do i loop over restrictions

Tags: grails, loops, createcriteria

i can do this:

```
def criteria = Category.createCriteria();
def results = criteria.list{ 
                          like('categoryName', "%abc%") or
                          like('categoryName', "%qwe%") 

                        };
```

but how i do it for unknown number of string values?
i would like do something like:

```
def results = criteria.list{  
for (str in strList){
like('categoryName', str) or
                          }
                        };
```

but ofcourse it doesnt work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `or { }`:

```
def criteria = Category.createCriteria()
def results = criteria.list {
    or {
        strList.each { str ->
            like('categoryName', "%${str}%")
        }
    }
}
```